# Access windows control panel items (applets) via c# code

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, controlpanel, windows-search

I am new to this and i have a small task. I want to access the `control panel items`, perform `search` and `display their name, description and task lists` etc what ever I can access in my window. Something similar to what windows explorer search does.

This is what I have done till now. I followed the approach [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6105/Enumerate-and-Host-Control-Panel-Applets-using-C) and I am able to access the cpl files in System folder. But they are not all the cpl files. And hence my result ends up being a subset of the desired result set.

Also by accessing the `cpl` files I do not get the `task list` and other details which are valuable in my search operation. Please see image for the result i want[image]

This result appears when i search for `display` inside the control panel explorer.

What else should I try? Can someone guide me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want find items in the WPF panels? Or applets panels? Maybe you must let it clear.

Comment: I want to display the control panel items and their task list in my project window. I need to know how can i access these items.